Creating a sqlite database file in a MAUI project folder
I created a new folder in my MAUI project and named it Database and would like this folder to be the destination of my.db3 file instead of FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, for testing purposes. So far I could not find a way to point to the correct path of this local project folder. I tried to copy the full path in my Solution Explorer, but passing this path did not work, maybe it needs to be formatted in a different way? I'm not sure.
C:\Users\UserA\source\repos\SolutionName\ProjectName\Database\

I'm assuming the following is a typical thought process of a Maui developer:

Create a local database file in a Maui project folder
When database is ready for deployment, move it manually to the Resources\Raw folder
Upon deployment, copy file to AppDataDirectory

Assuming this is an acceptable thought process, if not please correct me, how do I point to the correct path of a project folder?

files included in the project bundle are read-only at runtime.  If you want to include an existing DB in your project, you should put it in Resources/Raw and copy it to an app folder at startup

@Jason, does the bundle concept applies to all project folders or just the Resources folder? Because if it is the later, then this does not apply to the Database folder I created.

AFAIK anything included in the app bundle at build time is read-only.  This is definitely true on iOS and Android, not as positive about Windows

Jason is right anything added into the project is readonly
